# Using strace for a C file

Tags: c, strace

I have a C file that I want to trace what is going on. I'm trying to use:

```
strace -o trace.txt random.c
```

But it says that:

```
strace: Can't stat 'random.c': No such file or directory
```

I've been looking up strace for the past hour now, and don't exactly know what I'm doing wrong.
Is there an easier command to just trace what is compiled/executed?
Does 'strace' only work on shell files?

Comment: `*.c` files typically must be sacrificed to a compiler such as `gcc`, and the outcome of that then traced.

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418354/understanding-what-a-linux-binary-is-doing/418357#418357 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419697/why-are-true-and-false-so-large/419704#419704

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [thrig says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340351/using-strace-for-a-c-file#comment601677_340351), you must compile your C program (using a compiler such as `gcc` or `clang`), then use `strace` to run the compiled binary.

```
ek@Io:~$ cat >hello.c <<'EOF'
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main(void)
> {
>     puts("Hello, world!");
>     return 0;
> }
> EOF
ek@Io:~$ gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -g -o hello hello.c
ek@Io:~$ strace ./hello
execve("./hello", ["./hello"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x220f000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f8000316000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=156046, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 156046, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f80002ef000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1864888, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3967392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fffd2a000
mprotect(0x7f7fffee9000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f80000e9000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bf000) = 0x7f80000e9000
mmap(0x7f80000ef000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f80000ef000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f80002ee000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f80002ed000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f80002ec000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f80002ed700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f80000e9000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f8000318000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f80002ef000, 156046)          = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x220f000
brk(0x2230000)                          = 0x2230000
write(1, "Hello, world!\n", 14Hello, world!
)         = 14
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You may still of course use whatever options you need for `strace`, such as `-o`.

`strace` will not succeed at running C source code. Even if you give it a path with a `/` in it to insist that it attempt to do so, it will fail:

```
ek@Io:~$ strace hello.c
strace: Can't stat 'hello.c': No such file or directory
ek@Io:~$ strace ./hello.c
execve("./hello.c", ["./hello.c"], [/* 19 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "strace: exec: Permission denied\n", 32strace: exec: Permission denied
) = 32
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Even if you marked your `.c` file executable, it still cannot be run:

```
ek@Io:~$ chmod +x hello.c
ek@Io:~$ strace ./hello.c
execve("./hello.c", ["./hello.c"], [/* 19 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error
) = 32
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

In short, you have to compile your C program and run the compiled binary rather than the source code file itself. Just as you cannot run a `.c` file normally (i.e., `./hello.c` fails), you cannot run it with `strace` either.