# Tools for showing which files are accessed by a program?

Tags: linux, files, process, open-files

I'm not going for complicated tools like AppArmor complain mode, I need easy tools to  tell me which files are accessed by a specific program.

Comment: Under what Operating System?

Comment: Might also be useful to explain you expect the program to access files in what way - reading, writing, appending, only getting `fstat()` or `lstat()` info, etc.

Comment: Both Suse and Ubuntu

Comment: No mater what way I have to know, is it fstat() or lstat() are programming?

Comment: Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's comment in other words: if a program checks a file's length, modification date, permissions or other properties but not accessing the file's data, would you count it as "accessing the file" or not?

Answer (score 12):

Per Chris Down, you can use `strace -p` to examine an *already running* process, to see what files it opens from now until the time you terminate strace or the process itself finishes.

If you want to see files opened for the *entire duration* of a process, right from the start, use `strace` with the executable name.  Adding `-f` ensures that any forked sub-processes also get reported.  Example

```
# strace -e open -f /bin/id
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/thread-self/attr/current", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/self/task/1581/attr/current", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
+++ exited with 0 +++
#
```

Using `lsof` to see what files a process *currently* has open

```
# lsof -p $(pidof NetworkManager)
COMMAND   PID USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
NetworkMa 722 root  cwd       DIR              253,0       224       64 /
NetworkMa 722 root  rtd       DIR              253,0       224       64 /
NetworkMa 722 root  txt       REG              253,0   2618520   288243 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
NetworkMa 722 root  mem       REG              253,0     27776    34560 /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.17.so
[...]
#
```

If you have SystemTap, you can monitor the entire host for files being opened.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# cat mon
#!/usr/bin/env stap
probe syscall.open { printf ("pid %d program %s opened %s\n", pid(), execname(), filename) }
# ./mon
pid 14813 program touch opened "/etc/ld.so.cache"
pid 14813 program touch opened "/lib64/libc.so.6"
pid 14813 program touch opened 0x7f7a8c6ec8d0
pid 14813 program touch opened "foo2"
[...]
#
```

Comment: `open` isn't the only relevant system call. For example it is possible to pass file descriptors between processes over a unix socket, and there is the `openat` system call which can also open a file.

Comment: ---- SIGUSR1 {si_signo=SIGUSR1, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=6026, si_uid=1002} ----    whats that

Comment: kaspers, do I only need to search for 'openat' at the strace output command?

Comment: Trying open a file (but the file may not be exist) is displayed in the 'strace' outputs too?

Comment: Boll19, files that fail to open due to them not existing are happily reported within `strace`, see the ENOENT lines in the example.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `opensnoop` from BCC, which uses eBPF under the hood:

```
# ./opensnoop -p 1576
PID    COMM      FD ERR PATH
1576   snmpd     11   0 /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/forwarding
1576   snmpd     11   0 /proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/lo/base_reachable_time_ms
1576   snmpd      9   0 /proc/diskstats
1576   snmpd      9   0 /proc/stat
1576   snmpd      9   0 /proc/vmstat
[...]
```

This is quite performant since it uses kprobes instead of having to restart syscalls, like `strace` does.

You can also do this with `strace` (potentially with `-f` to follow the traced process' children), but its way of operating, involving restarting syscalls as part of [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) will slow down your application somewhat:

```
# strace -e open -p 15735
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
[...]
```

You can also start your application this way if desired, using `strace [executable]`, or `strace -f [executable]`.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite tool for monitoring which files an application opens is the powerful monitoring framework `sysdig`.

For monitoring all the open files opened by a program named `exe_file`:

```
sudo sysdig -p "proc.name=exe_file %12user.name %6proc.pid %12proc.name %3fd.num %fd.typechar %fd.name" evt.type=open
```

Monitoring all the files opened in the server:

```
sudo sysdig -p "%12user.name %6proc.pid %12proc.name %3fd.num %fd.typechar %fd.name" evt.type=open
```

Creating a trace file that will only contain writing events in home directories (which we can inspect later with `sysdig -r writetrace.scap.gz`):

```
sudo sysdig -p "%user.name %proc.name %fd.name" "evt.type=write and fd.name contains /home/" -z -w writetrace.scap.gz
```

Seeing everything at syscall level a process named `exe_file` does:

```
sudo sysdig proc.name=exe_file
```

Sysdig has many chisels, see for more interesting things it can do:

- [Sysdig Examples](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-Examples)
- [How to monitor and troubleshoot a Linux server using sysdig](http://xmodulo.com/monitor-troubleshoot-linux-server-sysdig.html)

You also have got `dtrace` that is not much used in Linux, but is still use a lot with *BSD operating systems:

```
# Files opened by process,
dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

Besides `sysdig`, `strace` and `dtrace`, you also have got `ltrace`, which records/intercepts signals/dynamic libraries/system calls which are called/received by a process:

> `ltrace` is a program that simply runs the specified command until it
>   exits. It intercepts and records the dynamic library calls which are
>   called by the executed process and the signals which are received by
>   that process. It can also intercept and print the system calls
>   executed by the program.

```
$ltrace exe_file
_libc_start_main(0x400624, 1, 0x7ffcb7b6d7c8, 0x400710 <unfinished ...>  
time(0)                                                                              = 1508018406  
srand(0x59e288e6, 0x7ffcb7b6d7c8, 0x7ffcb7b6d7d8, 0)                                 = 0  
sprintf("mkdir -p -- '/opt/sms/AU/mo'", "mkdir -p -- '%s'", "/opt/sms/AU/mo")        = 28  
system("mkdir -p -- '/opt/sms/AU/mo'" <no return ...>  
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) ---  
<... system resumed> )                                                               = 0  
rand(2, 0x7ffcb7b6d480, 0, 0x7f9d6d4622b0)                                           = 0x2d8ddbe1  
sprintf("/opt/sms/AU/mo/tmp.XXXXXX", "%s/tmp.XXXXXX", "/opt/sms/AU/mo")      = 29  
mkstemp(0x7ffcb7b6d5c0, 0x40080b, 0x40081a, 0x7ffffff1)                              = 3  
sprintf("/opt/sms/AU/mo/tmp.XXXXXX", "%s/tmp.XXXXXX", "/opt/sms/AU/mo")      = 29  
mkstemp(0x7ffcb7b6d5c0, 0x40080b, 0x40081a, 0x7ffffff1)                              = 4  
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

If the program is small, you might also consider disassembling it with `objdump -d exe_file` or disassembling/decompiling it with `Hopper`, to see all the files it deals with.

For more details see: [Understanding what a Linux binary is doing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418354/understanding-what-a-linux-binary-is-doing/418357)

As a first approach, I would also do:

```
strings exe_file
```

It is a low cost approach, and with luck some of the files names might just be present in ASCII mode in the binary file with luck.

See also related answer [Why are true and false so large?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419697/why-are-true-and-false-so-large/419704#419704)

If binaries/files that come with the distribution you can also fetch the sources from the sources repositories of the distribution, or the official repositories of the actual utility.

As a last resource, you can always use tools like [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) or [rr](http://rr-project.org) to debug the binary in real time.

Comment: aaa43bb66:~ # sudo proc.name=exe_file sysdig -p "%12user.name %6proc.pid %12proc.name %3fd.num %fd.typechar %fd.name" evt.type=open
    Unable to load the driver    error opening device /dev/sysdig0. Make sure you have root credentials and that the sysdig-probe module is loaded.

Comment: /*<pre>aaa43bb66:~ # sudo proc.name=exe_file sysdig -p "%12user.name %6proc.pid %12proc.name %3fd.num %fd.typechar %fd.name" evt.type=open
    Unable to load the driver    error opening device /dev/sysdig0. Make sure you have root credentials and that the sysdig-probe module is loaded.<code>*/

Comment: @Boll19 Got an error there, corrected it. That message seems about a `sysdig` bug (are you using ARM?), please post a new question for it.