# Why doesn't `strace` show this process is waiting for something?

Tags: performance, time, strace

The mighty `strace` has let me down.  How is this possible?

---

`time foo` shows that `foo` takes several seconds to run ("real"), but uses negligible cpu time, both in userspace ("user") and in the kernel ("sys").  For the curious, `foo` is defined below.

So it spends most of its time waiting for something else, not executing CPU instructions.  Normally, I can see how it is waiting in `strace` - i.e. what system call is blocking for a long period of time.  Unfortunately this approach didn't work.

`strace -ttt -T -C -w foo` shows system calls, timestamped, and a summary of the (real) time spent in system calls.  But this particular process showed as spending negligible overall (real) time inside system calls.

---

`foo` is actually `journalctl -b -u dev-hugepages.mount`.  Except that I had to change the last argument to a different systemd unit each time in order to reproduce this.  In other words, the delay I am investigating happened the first time that I try to get the logs for any one systemd unit.  **EDIT**: after answering the main question, I also realized [the reason I was having this problem reproducing the delay](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420299/why-is-sync-drop-caches-not-dropping-caches/420300).

The time spent by this process is a specific issue, apparently it does not occur on all systems. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7963

Comment: Hmm... since your "foo" program is not just a simple single-process, single-threaded process, you would be better served by telling strace to follow and attach to forks. '-ff' is your friend! :) You'll also want to, then, use "-o /dev/shm/strace-foo" to corrall all those strafe process output files into one location. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @JesseAdelman I think `journalctl` runs one process only.  I have a feeling `journalctl` uses one extra thread for whatever reason - iirc there was one clone() call.  I think this means you are technically correct, but it is also technically irrelevant to the question.  `time` looks at the process as a whole, and has shown that the process as a whole is rather sleepy (blocking on something).  `strace` did not show enough sleeps.  It doesn't matter if a second thread is sleeping, the main thread must also be very sleepy to explain the `time` result.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The usual reason for hitting this issue, is that the process is blocking in page faults.  These are reads or possibly writes to files performed through a memory mapping aka `mmap()`.  You may have noticed some `mmap()` in the trace of system calls.

If you had used the `/usr/bin/time` program instead of the `time` shell builtin, you might also have noticed:

```
0.04user 0.10system 0:02.29elapsed 6%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 40464maxresident)k
73632inputs+0outputs (376major+1081minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

`major` pagefaults are the ones that require filesystem IO.  `minor` pagefaults are much less significant (probably only a "TLB miss").

I suspect `inputs` are the total number of pages read.  Currently, I think file mapped pages are always the same size.  4096 bytes in most cases, but you can check `getconf PAGESIZE`.

So this represents ~290 megabytes, read at something over 100 megabytes per second, a standard speed for a hard disk like mine.  Mystery solved!

---

Note also, you are assuming that you have a whole free CPU for this process.  Otherwise, the process could simply be blocked waiting for other processes to yield the CPU.

`strace` only shows when the process enters (and then leaves) the kernel due to a system call.  Or when a unix signal is delivered.  However there are other types of interrupts which `strace` does not show at all.  So these include

- Page faults.
- The timer interrupt.  This is used to switch to a different process, when the current one has exhausted its allocated time slice on the CPU.

Comment: Good answer, congrats! It is indeed important to understand the limitations of the tools one is using. +1 ; I also enjoy these subject: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418354/understanding-what-a-linux-binary-is-doing/418357#418357 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419697/why-are-true-and-false-so-large/419704#419704