# Why is `sync + drop_caches` not dropping caches?

Tags: linux-kernel, performance, cache, benchmark

I have a test case for [`journalctl` where it spends several seconds reading from the disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420288/why-doesnt-strace-show-this-process-is-waiting-for-something/420289).  But if I try to benchmark multiple runs of the test case, I find that it's impossibly fast after the first run.  Even if I try to drop caches.  Why?

```
$ sync && echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && /usr/bin/time journalctl -b -u dev-shm.mount
1
0.01user 0.03system 0:04.50elapsed 1%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 30956maxresident)k
95424inputs+0outputs (424major+665minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ sync && echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && /usr/bin/time journalctl -b -u dev-shm.mount >/dev/null
1
0.00user 0.01system 0:00.08elapsed 26%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 31832maxresident)k
94992inputs+0outputs (422major+445minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Interestingly `time` still shows it doing lots of IO through page faults (`inputs`).  I notice that if I skip the `drop_caches` between runs, it shows 0 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drop_caches` only affects the kernel filesystem cache.  It does not affect caches in the underlying hardware.  Apparently your hardware has hundreds of  megabytes of cache (94992 * 4096 ~= 400MB).  Awesome!

In my case, it is because the kernel is running in a VM.  So the "underlying hardware" is not a simple hard disk.  This illustrates the disk settings used by `virt-manager`.

---

The option used for "caching mode" respects write flushes (using `fsync()`), but otherwise allows caching both writes and reads in the host kernel's page cache.  The "underlying hardware" effectively includes a disk cache within the the host's RAM, potentially growing to multiple gigabytes.

libvirt / KVM calls this "writeback" caching.

I've also noticed that this speeds up rebooting the VM.