# Possible limiting factor during upgrade of Fedora VM - not disk or cpu or network?

Tags: fedora, virtual-machine, upgrade, performance, atop

I'm upgrading a VM from Fedora 29 to Fedora 30.  I triggered the update from inside GNOME Software.  It downloaded the upgrade, and asked to reboot.  It started installing...

`atop` shows the `qemu` process using about 15% of one CPU core.  And my one hard drive at about 15% utilization.

What other resource(s) could the VM possibly be waiting for, the other ~ 70% of the time?  Is it just [sleepy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(system_call))??  Is there some other way to explain or find this out?

The upgrade showed the normal progress indicator, and completed without errors.

The VM is in libvirt (virt-manager), using the default KVM backend on x86-64.  I configured the VM disk using cache mode "none".  There's a 2x2 matrix of caching options; "none" means O_DIRECT, but not O_SYNC.  (My intent was to avoid [filling the host kernel's writeback cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474119/system-lags-when-doing-large-r-w-operations-on-external-disks/474171); at least it seems to have left the host system so much more responsive than the last time I tried this).  "IO Mode" is set to "Hypervisor default".  The virtual disk controller is using VirtIO.  libvirt is from Fedora 29; it is version 4.7.0 and qemu is version 3.0.0.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the VM console?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think `virt-manager` shows a small visual graph of CPU usage with no numbers on it, but nothing else.  I guess I should check that graph is consistent with `atop`, I suspect it will be though.  I'm not planning to retest right now, but I plan to check the `atop` output against artificial loads (`stress`, `dd`, maybe a random write load as well) inside the VM.

Comment: Eh? You know how to look at the virtual machine console, right? Double click on the VM's row in virt-manager.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ... that's how I logged in and ran GNOME Software to trigger the update, yes :-).  The update completed as expected, and I was able to watch the progress % messages (which sadly have been fighting with the systemd [cylon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQfOwtBe9Bs)).  I'll edit a bit to clarify.