# dd command oflag direct and sync flags

Tags: dd

I have the below shell script and I wonder whether **oflag**'s **direct** does the **sync**ing automatically or if it is explicitly required:

```
dd bs=10M oflag=direct,sync of=ofile.bin
```

Also what is the difference in saying **oflag=sync** and **conv=sync** and **conv=fsync**?

What impact does it have if I change the code to the line below?

```
dd bs=10M conv=fsync oflag=direct of=ofile.bin
```

Comment: direct uses direct i/o, without buffer cache (check your blocksize though), oflag=sync uses synchronous data/metadata processing. conv=fsync uses sync() call after processing, conv=sync pads input blocks with zeroes to the blocksize.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We can probably rule out `conv=sync` to start with.  It does something rather different, which I expect you do not want :-).

> pad  every  input  block  with  NULs to ibs-size; when used with
> block or unblock, pad with spaces rather than NULs

---

`oflag=direct` does not sync automatically on its own.[*]

`conv=fsync` differs from `oflag=sync`.  `oflag=sync` effectively syncs after each output block.  `conv=fsync` does one sync at the end.

The end result is the same, but the performance along the way is different :-).

1. `oflag=sync` could be significantly slower.  You can mitigate this, by increasing the block size.
2. If device-specific caches are large[1], this will affect the progress reported e.g. by the `status=progress` option.
3. If you do *not* use `oflag=direct`, then large amounts of writes can build up in the system page cache.  This build-up will affect the progress you see[2].  But also, Linux sometimes responds badly to the build-up, and degrades performance for *all* devices[3].

---

[1] "Apparently your hardware has hundreds of megabytes of cache... In my case, it is because the kernel is [actually running inside a virtual machine]". https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420300/29483

[2] [Why does a gunzip to dd pipeline slow down at the end?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467844/why-does-a-gunzip-to-dd-pipeline-slow-down-at-the-end/)

[3] [System lags when doing large R/W operations on external disks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474119/system-lags-when-doing-large-r-w-operations-on-external-disks/)

[*] *When you write directly to a block device node*, Linux syncs the block device when it is closed (and is not open by any other program).  See: [Block device cache v.s. a filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473854/29483). Sometimes I see people who do not use an explicit sync when writing to a block device.  It will often seem to work OK... until it doesn't.  So I recommend at least using `conv=fsync`.

Comment: Thank  you very much for your answer. It explains everything clearly except `oflag=direct `. I still don't understand why you don't recommend `direct` option. I prefer `direct` and I think that will direct write to file/device without worrying about the cache and memory. Can you explain a bit more on `oflag=direct`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Actually I asked another dd question before receiving your response in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656264. Nobody replied me yet. If you have time, you can have a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, the thing I'm saying not to rely on, is that oflag=direct on a Linux block device sort-of implies conv=fsync. Except that it does not report errors, and it won't fsync if something else also had the device open when you closed it. I think if you want fsync behaviour, you should ask for it explicitly. Edited to be more clear.