# Alpine version-sort

Tags: sort, busybox, alpine-linux

How to do `sort -V` in alpine linux?

```
sort: unrecognized option: V
BusyBox v1.28.4 (2018-12-06 15:13:21 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: sort [-nrugMcszbdfiokt] [-o FILE] [-k start[.offset][opts][,end[.offset][opts]] [-t CHAR] [FILE]...

Sort lines of text

    -o FILE Output to FILE
    -c  Check whether input is sorted
    -b  Ignore leading blanks
    -f  Ignore case
    -i  Ignore unprintable characters
    -d  Dictionary order (blank or alphanumeric only)
    -g  General numerical sort
    -M  Sort month
    -n  Sort numbers
    -t CHAR Field separator
    -k N[,M] Sort by Nth field
    -r  Reverse sort order
    -s  Stable (don't sort ties alphabetically)
    -u  Suppress duplicate lines
    -z  Lines are terminated by NUL, not newline
```

Comment: This relates as well to 'sort -h'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Alpine, you can add GNU sort via the `coreutils` package:

```
apk add coreutils
```

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `sort` in release 1.30.0 of BusyBox (December 2018) introduced `-V` for doing "version sorting", just like in GNU `sort`.

BusyBox 1.30.1 was included in Alpine Linux in release 3.10 (June 2019), so you do not need the `coreutils` package anymore.

Comment: While the short form `-V` seems to be supported, the long-form `--version-sort` seems not supported. So make sure you use the short form if you want a portable solution.

Comment: Busybox sort has functional differences as compared to GNU sort. So, it may not be a drop-in replacement. E.g. If a folder has files named `01 A`, `02 B` & `011 C`, GNU sort gives `A, B, C`, while Busybox gives `A C B`. So, you may still need `coreutils`.

Answer (score 1):

In alpine, sort - V (version) is not supported.

Bear in mind that it's the busybox version and not the coreutis sort version.

Such is the price to pay to have a very light distribution.

Note that you can always add compiled binaries and glibc itself to alpine, or even static linked j binaries, but once you start doing that, you are adding more substantial size to it.

Comment: There is also posts about how to working around not having sort here, I am in my the tube now, cannot get links

Comment: I installed `coreutils` instead of out of the box one, and it works

Comment: Yeah, it works adding it, though I am no alpine user. The point is that coreutils is big. If you keep adding size to alpine, it comes to a point where it could make more sense using a cut down image of Debian., you can make 200-300 MB images of Debian, already with APT and security updates if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I know and agree what you say, the filesize of coreutils is not small for alpine but it is still acceptable for my use case as I'm not deploying it to an embedded device, thus, it would be a good balance for me :)

Comment: See related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419697/why-are-true-and-false-so-large/419704#419704 ; however my concerns about Alpine is that once you lose that size advantage, it does not make sense keeping using it. (less supported, binaries built with musl instead of glibc, probably less updates during lesser time)